How can I launch PowerShell as a post-build step in MSBuild?
Currently, you cannot easily debug a binary PowerShell module in Visual Studio 2022 (not Code!).
Instead of being required to manually open a PowerShell session, change the location to my project, attach the debugger to it, import my module and run one of my functions, I'd like to have a new PowerShell automatically opened and do all these things up to importing my module by using an MSBuild PostBuild step.
The following .NET project file entry doesn't work:
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="Start-Process -FilePath pwsh -ArgumentList &quot;-NoExit -Command Set-Location '$(OutputPath)'&quot;" />
</Target>

MSBuild returns the following error then:
1>The command "Start-Process" is either misspelled or could not be found.
1>My.csproj(23,5): error MSB3073: The command "Start-Process -FilePath pwsh -ArgumentList "-NoExit -Command Set-Location 'bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\'"" exited with code 9009.

From the error I can see that it's not PowerShell that's executing the command but the Console.
How can I successfully open a new PowerShell window from a post-build step using MSBuild?
EDIT
If I just run <Exec Command="pwsh" /> (which should work without flaw), I get the following build error:
1>PowerShell 7.4.2
1>[31;1m´╗┐: [31;1mThe term '´╗┐' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.[0m
1>[31;1m[31;1mCheck the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.[0m
1>PS C:\MyPSModule> ´╗┐PS C:\MyPSModule>
1>C:\MyPSModule\MyPSModule.csproj(36,5): error MSB3073: The "pwsh" command exited with code 1.


TL;DR: You need to tell CMD to invoke PowerShell like you would in TaskScheduler. Currently you are trying to directly invoke a PS cmdlet which CMD has no idea about.

@Filburt: My question is different, please refer to my edit.

Plus: The above won't open a new, interactive PowerShell window.

If you just run pwsh and receive an error, it is likely because of something in your PS profile (hint: C:\MyPSModule). Did you try just to open CMD and run pwsh?

If you expect your Exec Command to open an interactive PS console, you need to instruct CMD to do so. Again: trying to directly invoke Start-Process is not going to work. CMD has no clue what to do with that.

The Exec task always creates an instance of cmd and passes the value of Command. You need to use a command that cmd will understand. Try <Exec Command="pwsh -NoExit -NoProfile -WorkingDirectory &quot;$(OutputPath)&quot;" />

Just tried and I think <Exec Command="start pwsh" /> will take you where you want to go.

If you want to start a new, interactive PowerShell window from an MSBuild Exec task, you need to use the start command to instruct CMD to create a new process instead of switching to the PowerShell conhost within the same window:
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
  <Exec Command="start pwsh" />
</Target>

